# Properly citing an image from a website

Tags: citations, website

I'm using an image from https://fermi.gsfc.nasa.gov/science/eteu/agn/ on the Unified Model of AGNs, and I've captioned it

```
The AGN unified model, showing the BLR and NLR, as well as different types
based on the observational angle. Credit: Fermi and NASA: 
https://fermi.gsfc.nasa.gov/science/eteu/agn/
```

As far as I can see, the image is not from an original paper. Is this an appropriate way to cite the website? What's the best way to include a citation for an image from a website?

Comment: Any reference that includes a link and many other internet resources should include a date at which you accessed it. You don't have any control over wha will happen to that site.